# How do I change the order in a graph where the categories are not all numeric in ggplot2?

Tags: r, visualization, ggplot2

I recently made a graph where the Shoot response is categorized and put into percentages (see graph). [image] Now the problem is that Hanging and Dislodged should be the other way around. How can I change this?
This is the code I have used:

```
ggplot(Data11, aes(x=Species, y =Percentage, fill = as.factor(reorder( Dam_angle ,desc( Dam_angle )))))
 geom_bar(stat = "identity")+
 
 facet_grid(.~Erosion, scales = "free_x")+
 
 scale_y_continuous(labels=scales::percent, "Percentage of shoots per response category") +
 
 scale_fill_brewer("Shoot response category",palette = "RdYlGn")+
 
labs(title="Erosion (cm)",x = "Species")+
 theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))+
 
 theme_bw()+
 
 theme(strip.background=element_rect(fill = "white"),strip.text = element_text(face = "bold"),axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45,vjust = 1, hjust = 1))
```

Comment: I think something like `fill = as.factor(reorder( Dam_angle ,desc( Dam_angle ))) |> forcats::fct_relevel("Dislodged", after = Inf)` should work.